# MySQL text indices w/ no stop words or min word length

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, stop-words

I'm interesting in performing full text searches in MySQL, but the words that I am specifically interested in, will tend to be short words, or words that will likely appear on the stop list. For example, I might want to search for all entries that begin with "It is".

What is the best approach to this? Should I just manually remove all the stop words and set the min word length to 0? Or is there another way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my.ini text file (MySQL) :

```
ft_stopword_file = ""   or link an empty file "empty_stopwords.txt"
ft_min_word_len = 2
```

// set your minimum length, but be aware that shorter words (3,2) will increase the query time dramatically, especially if the fulltext indexed column fields are large.

Save the file, restart the server.

The next step should be to repair the indexes with this query:

```
REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK.
```

However, this will not work if you table is using InnoDB storage engine. You will have to change it to MyISAM :

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

So, once again:

1. Edit my.ini file and save
2. Restart your server (this cannot be done dynamically)
3. Change the table engine (if needed)  ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENGINE = MyISAM;
4. Perform repair                       REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK.

Be aware that InnoDB and MyISAM have their speed differences. One read faster, other writes faster ( read more about that on the internet )